# Entering custom date for event in iOS Calendar app

Tags: ios, calendar

I want to add a historical date in the iOS Calendar app. To do this I currently have to flick through the date picker control like forever, until I roll back to where I want.

This is appalling slow and frustrating. Is there a way of just entering the date I want?

Answer (score 3):

For older dates it‘s easier to navigate to the date first, and enter the event there:

- Switch to year view (tap the Month and Year label at top left)
- Scroll back in time to the year you want to add the event
- Tap on the day you want to add the event on
- Tap ＋ as usual